# Reorder dataset with qualitative information

Tags: r

I'm trying to *reorder* a dataset (financial currency data) with certain criteria. Each column has a code to address which type of data we are dealing with.

Basically I want to reorder this column that i splitted, so that all the data of the same currency are grouped togheter. This information is stored in the 10th element of each row of this dataset (i.e `reord[[1]][10] == "USD")`. So I need to create an index to reorder this data.

This is a part of the original column that addresses the type of data that i splitted:

```
 reord = list(c("H", "A", "A", "B", "5J", "A", "5J", "A", "TO1", "USD", 
"A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "D", "R", "B", "5J", "C", "5J", "A", 
"TO1", "CAD", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "A", "I", "B", "5J", 
"A", "5J", "A", "TO1", "JPY", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "A", 
"R", "B", "5J", "C", "5J", "A", "TO1", "$TO1+TO1-USD-EUR-JPY-GBP-CHF-CAD-SEK", 
"A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "D", "I", "B", "5J", "U", "5J", "A", 
"TO1", "JPY", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "A", "D", "B", "5J", 
"C", "5J", "A", "TO1", "EUR", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "D", 
"R", "B", "5J", "A", "5J", "A", "TO1", "SEK", "A", "A", "3", 
"C"), c("H", "Q", "C", "B", "5J", "B", "5J", "A", "TO1", "USD", 
"A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "D", "S", "B", "5J", "U", "5J", "A", 
"TO1", "JPY", "A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "A", "R", "B", "5J", 
"U", "5J", "A", "TO1", "SEK", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "A", 
"R", "B", "5J", "B", "5J", "A", "TO1", "$TO1+TO1-USD-EUR-JPY-GBP-CHF-CAD-SEK", 
"A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "A", "S", "B", "5J", "B", "5J", "A", 
"TO1", "JPY", "A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "D", "D", "B", "5J", 
"U", "5J", "A", "TO1", "JPY", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "D", 
"S", "B", "5J", "A", "5J", "A", "TO1", "$TO1+TO1-USD-EUR-JPY-GBP-CHF-CAD-SEK", 
"A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "D", "S", "B", "5J", "A", "5J", "A", 
"TO1", "GBP", "A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "D", "I", "B", "5J", 
"K", "5J", "A", "TO1", "CAD", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "D", 
"R", "B", "5J", "K", "5J", "A", "TO1", "CHF", "A", "A", "3", 
"C"), c("H", "A", "T", "B", "5J", "K", "5J", "A", "TO1", "JPY", 
"A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "D", "T", "B", "5J", "U", "5J", "A", 
"TO1", "CAD", "A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "Q", "C", "B", "5J", 
"A", "5J", "A", "TO1", "USD", "A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "A", 
"D", "B", "5J", "B", "5J", "A", "TO1", "EUR", "A", "A", "3", 
"C"), c("H", "A", "S", "B", "5J", "C", "5J", "A", "TO1", "EUR", 
"A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "D", "D", "B", "5J", "K", "5J", "A", 
"TO1", "CAD", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "D", "R", "B", "5J", 
"B", "5J", "A", "TO1", "SEK", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "D", 
"R", "B", "5J", "K", "5J", "A", "TO1", "TO1", "A", "A", "3", 
"C"), c("H", "D", "S", "B", "5J", "B", "5J", "A", "TO1", "$TO1+TO1-USD-EUR-JPY-GBP-CHF-CAD-SEK", 
"A", "A", "3", "A"), c("H", "D", "S", "B", "5J", "C", "5J", "A", 
"TO1", "$TO1+TO1-USD-EUR-JPY-GBP-CHF-CAD-SEK", "A", "A", "3", 
"A"), c("H", "D", "I", "B", "5J", "A", "5J", "A", "TO1", "GBP", 
"A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "A", "D", "B", "5J", "A", "5J", "A", 
"TO1", "JPY", "A", "A", "3", "C"), c("H", "A", "D", "B", "5J", 
"K", "5J", "A", "TO1", "$TO1+TO1-USD-EUR-JPY-GBP-CHF-CAD-SEK", 
"A", "A", "3", "C"))
```

I obtained the output I wanted but in a naive way:

```
##Want to find the index of all the USD elements in the 10th position in everyrow
idxUSA = NULL
idxEUR = NULL
idxCHF = NULL
idxJPY = NULL
idxSEK = NULL
idxGBP = NULL
idxCAD = NULL
idxTO1 = NULL
idxOTHER = NULL
for(i in 1:length(reord)) {

  if(reord[[i]][10] == "USD") {
    print(reord[[i]][10])
  idxUSA = c(idxUSA,i)
  }

  if(reord[[i]][10] == "EUR") {
    print(reord[[i]][10])
    idxEUR = c(idxEUR,i)
  }

  if(reord[[i]][10] == "JPY") {
    print(reord[[i]][10])
    idxJPY = c(idxJPY,i)
  }

  if(reord[[i]][10] == "TO1") {
    print(reord[[i]][10])
    idxTO1 = c(idxTO1,i)
  }

  if(reord[[i]][10] == "SEK") {
    print(reord[[i]][10])
    idxSEK = c(idxSEK,i)
  }

  if(reord[[i]][10] == "CHF") {
    print(reord[[i]][10])
    idxCHF = c(idxCHF,i)
  }

   if(reord[[i]][10] == "GBP") {
    print(reord[[i]][10])
    idxGBP = c(idxGBP,i)
  }

  if(reord[[i]][10] == "CAD") {
    print(reord[[i]][10])
    idxCAD = c(idxCAD,i)
  }

  if(reord[[i]][10] == "$TO1+TO1-USD-EUR-JPY-GBP-CHF-CAD-SEK") {
    print(reord[[i]][10])
    idxOTHER = c(idxOTHER,i)
  }
}
```

How can I optimize this process? Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming i've understood correctly, you could do this

```
tenth <- sapply(reord, `[`, 10)
idx <- split(seq_along(tenth), tenth)
```

First we create a vector with the tenth element of each item in the list. Then we split the indexed up by the values. So now we can get all the index for the USD values with

```
idx$USD
# [1]  1  8 20
# or idx[["USD"]]
```

and then if the desired result is to sort the original list, we can unlist the groupings of indexes and use that to index the original list with

```
reord[unlist(idx)]
```

This will group all the currencies together.